# Azure Cognitive Search Complex Json in Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Set up the free tier of Cog Search, pointed it at an Azure Blob Container with a hierarchy and about 500 json docs that look like the below. The import wizard detected nothing real and spit out some metadata for indexing.

I experimented with the json array type but can't seem to get the syntax down so that the repeated metadata items can be indexed individually, and the first one "Name":"id" "Value":"{guid} can be used as the key, and "alternateQuestions" can be indexed/queried individually as well. What is the right way to do this?

Thanks.

```
{
"itemSet": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "answer": "lorem ipsum \n  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque sodales augue.  ",
        "questions": [
            "thing 1" ,
            "thing2" 
        ],
        "learningBits": [
            {
              "alternateQuestions": [
                {  "question" : "alt 1?" , "userSuggestedCount" : 1 , "autoSuggestedCount" : 0 } , 
                {  "question" : "alt 2?" , "userSuggestedCount" : 1 , "autoSuggestedCount" : 0 } 
              ]
            }
          ] ,
        "metadata": [
            {
                "Name": "id" , "Value": "90d8a1fa-1aa3-47d5-8f92-1528d1998b15"
            },
            {
                "Name": "people",
                "Value": "person1,person2"
            },
            {
                "Name": "linkUris",
                "Value": "site1;site2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

index:

```
    {
  "@odata.context": "https://cf0e1cogs01.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DBD5B20715B8A7\"",
  "name": "azureblob-index",
  "defaultScoringProfile": "",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "content",
      "type": "Edm.ComplexType",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "version",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": null,
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "answer",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": true,
          "retrievable": true,
          "sortable": true,
          "facetable": true,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_content_type",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_size",
      "type": "Edm.Int64",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_last_modified",
      "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_content_md5",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_name",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_file_extension",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_content_encoding",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_content_type",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_language",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": null,
  "vectorSearch": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not adding the correct parsing mode as part of your data source definition as per [How to index JSON blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs).

If you choose the parsing mode you expect, you will see the schema being detected correctly:

[image]

Index schema detected:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, because the id value is always "0", and the actual GUID is an object in the metadata section, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please open a support case in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request so our support team is able to ask for all the details to make your scenario work. We can't ask for more details here since we cannot ask for specific definitions that are considered customer data and we cannot request other than in a support case, not publicly. Thanks.

Comment: that opens a case for paid support. I am trying to get this to use my json, not sure why I have to pay for something that should have a public example.

Comment: We usually recommend to open support cases in case they're part of your Azure subscription, not to pay for extra support. We will check with our internal personnel if there is a way to help online, this may take some time. Thanks for waiting in advance.